# Missing parameters with RESTful request when upgrading to Grails 2.3.0

Tags: rest, grails, extjs

I am using Grails with RESTful to develop my web application. Everything works fine, till I upgrade my application to Grails 2.3. Here is my UrlMappings:
I still send request, submit or do some other things normally, but in POST, PUT requests, the parameters are missing. Server just recognize only the parameters I put on the URL directly, but the remain I enclose in form or model when submit cannot be found in the "params" variable. He is my UrlMappings:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ constraints {} }

        name apiSingle: "/api/$controller/$id"(parseRequest:true){
            action = [GET: "show", PUT: "update", DELETE: "delete"]
            constraints { id(matches:/\d+/) }
        }
        name apiCollection: "/api/$controller"(parseRequest:true){
            action = [GET: "list", POST: "save"]
        }

        name api2: "/api/$controller/$action"(parseRequest:true)
        name api3: "/api/$controller/$action/$id"(parseRequest:true)

        "/"(view:"/welcome")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

I have read the latest document of Grails 2.3, at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#restfulMappings
but I think it is not clear. I have tried it follow the documentation but have no result. And there are no any sample about using Grails 2.3 with RESTful for me to refer.
How can I make it work normally as before, and can access all parameter values in REST request? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you find them in `request` instead of `params`?

Comment: @dmahapatro: No, I still don't see them. But if yes, why are those parameter attached to 'request' instead of 'params' as usual?

Comment: Because POST/PUT sends a request body instead and ideally there is no need of Query params. But I m not sure what the issue would be in your case, until it is tested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-and-parsing-json-td4649119.html `parseRequest` has no effect since Grails 2.3

If you use JSON as request body you can accees request params as `request.JSON.paramName`

As a workaround you can add a filter that will populate data from JSON to params:

```
class ParseRequestFilters {

    def filters = {
        remoteCalls(uri: "/remote/**") {
            before = {
                if (request.JSON) {
                    log.debug("Populating parsed json to params")
                    params << request.JSON
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if one _doesn't_ use JSON as the request body? Why doesn't the parsing logic work the same way for all methods?!

Comment: As far as I understand, the answer is that all controllers and methods under "/remote/**" does use JSON as the request body.

Comment: We have a need to support both `form-data` and `application/json` content types for our API and earlier versions of grails (eg. 2.2.x) made it easy to treat all bodies equally by making it possible to push everything into the `param` object. Is this still possible?

Comment: I think yes, it is possible. If you use forms, the input data will be in params by Grails population. If you use JSON, the input data will be *added* to the params by this filter.

Comment: The problem is that `params << request.JSON` doesn't make data on the params object look the same. Params will allow both exploded access (`params.user.username`) as well as unexploded (`params."user.username"`). Injecting the JSON doesn't allow for the unexploded access, which our current logic uses.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Kipriz's answer and cdeszaq's comment, you can write a recursive method to inject nested params. Something along these lines:

```
public void processNestedKeys(Map requestMap, String key) {
    if (getParameterValue(requestMap, key) instanceof JSONObject) {
        String nestedPrefix = key + ".";
        Map nestedMap = getParameterValue(requestMap, key)
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : nestedMap.entrySet()) {
            String newKey = nestedPrefix + entry.key;
            requestMap.put(newKey, getParameterValue(nestedMap, entry.key))
            processNestedKeys(requestMap, "${nestedPrefix + entry.key}");
        }
    }
}

public static Map populateParamsFromRequestJSON(def json) {
    Map requestParameters = json as ConcurrentHashMap
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : requestParameters.entrySet()) {
        processNestedKeys(requestParameters, entry.key)
    }

    return requestParameters
}
```