# Grails "params" doesn't contain json payload for REST controllers

Tags: json, rest, grails

I'm writing REST API for my app.

Using JSON payload in the POST request:

```
{
   availableAfter: "2014-03-16"
   canRead: true
   rightName: "dsa"
}
```

The problem is that, in the controller's params there are no values from payload.
But, despite that, I can read them using `properties[*]` syntax, like this:

```
right.properties['rightName', 'canRead'] = params;
right.availableAfter = params.date('availableAfter', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Properties 'rightName' and 'canRead' are set OK. 'availableAfter' is not(null even if taken with `params.availableAfter`).

Why is it differs?

UPDATE: Grails v 2.3.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `request.JSON` to get a hold of your JSON-body.
The `params` object doesn't contain it, unless you serialize your JSON object in the client and pass it as a parameter.

Comment: But why I can read it from params like this: 

right.properties['rightName', 'canRead'] = params;

Comment: print out the `params` and see what it contains

Comment: When you print it, it doesn't contain the payload. I understand that I can fetch it from request.JSON. It's not clear, why the above syntax works.

Comment: can it be, that those fields have default values?

Comment: No, they don't. ['rightName', 'canRead']  fields change depending on what I enter on client side

Comment: hmm might be an undocumented feature or side-effect of some kind

Comment: Check you UrlMappings - I believe it's because "parseRequest" argument set to true.

Comment: I tried once to find some info on 'parseRequest', but without success

Comment: according to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870003/missing-parameters-with-restful-request-when-upgrading-to-grails-2-3-0 , 
parseRequest has no effect since Grails 2.3

Comment: I saw it first in a Grails 1.3.7 project